# How to make sure certifi python package is up to date

Tags: tls, certificates, certificate-authority, python

In python's requests module documentation, I find this important recommendation:

> For the sake of security we recommend upgrading certifi frequently!

Q: How can I make sure that my system's `certifi` is up to date?

Comment: How did you install the module?  Did you use pip?

Comment: Not sure if it gets automatically downloaded with the `requests` module which I installed using `pip3`? But I tried to `pip3 install certifi` and got: `Requirement already satisfied: certifi in /home/e/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Upgrading certifi installed by pip3 can be done using the following

```
pip3 install certifi --upgrade
```

Requests just uses the installed certificate module.

Comment: This is what I get after executing the command: `Requirement already up-to-date: certifi in /home/e/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages`.

Comment: Looks like you're up to date then